# Best way to solve equation using SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am experiencing difficulties solving the following equation(eq1):

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, nsolve

index = 3586

cf = [202.31091967441085,
 215.90288600761673,
 230.4080089272309,
 245.88763753689724,
 262.4072425909973,
 272.4574399822326]

x = symbols('x')
eq1 = Eq(
    -index+ 
    cf[0]/1+x + 
    cf[1]/(1+x)**2 + 
    cf[2]/(1+x)**3+ 
    cf[3]/(1+x)**4+ 
    (cf[4]+(cf[5]/x))/1+x**5
    ,0 )
                                                                                        
sol = solve(eq1)
sol
```

This returns:

```
[-1.48603709844580,
 -0.410641978676901,
 0.104472587998023,
 4.97715154754751,
 -4.0596391945598 - 2.942001502084*I,
 -4.0596391945598 + 2.942001502084*I,
 -1.06017855850019 - 0.495183852591311*I,
 -1.06017855850019 + 0.495183852591311*I,
 1.52734522384858 - 4.75571183771098*I,
 1.52734522384858 + 4.75571183771098*I]
```

Although the expected answer (0.104472) is returned, this seems not to be the way to solve the equation. After reading other postings on this site, I was thinking using **nsolve** instead of **solve** to solve my problem. But I am struggeling how to use initial guess. When I use 0.1, I get the correct(expected) answer returned.

```
res = nsolve(eq1,x, 0.1)
print(res)

0.104472587998023
```

but when I change it to 0.06..

```
res = nsolve(eq1,x, 0.06)
print(res)
-1.48603709844580
```

Can someone help me use SymPy to solve this equation?

Comment: The expression `cf[0]/1+x` looks different than the others and a bit strange. Did you mean by any chance `cf[0]/(1+x)`? Same comment for `/1+x**5`. Also, what do you mean "this seems not to be the way to solve the equation."?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @vladmihaisima. I mean that I need only one answer returned. In this case i am trying to recreate an excel sheet, so i know the correct answer. But when the inputs for index and cf change, its a guess. In essence I am trying to calculate an [IRR](https://numpy.org/numpy-financial/latest/irr.html), where the 20/(1+r)**4 in this example is replaced by(cf[4]+cf[5]/x)//1+x**5. That's also the reason I can't use IRR

Comment: You can use `nsolve` and get one root, you can use `solve` to get all roots. But in general, you can not ask the machine to give you only the root you like. The right guess speeds up the search but does give the closest in your sense. If you have some specific requirements like that your root must lay in [0, 1] you may use `solveset(eq1, x, domain=Interval(0, 1))`.